# Availability of pdf2htmlex package in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pdf, conversion, format-conversion

pdf2htmlex is available in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but it is removed in 18.04.

Will it return to official repository? If yes, then when?

Answer (score 2):

The pdf2htmlEX development has been picked up by others again, and the deb files they put on GitHub work for me (xubuntu 18.04):

https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX/releases/tag/v0.16.0-poppler-0.62.0-ubuntu-18.04